# vBulletin 5 + lighttpd url rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, vbulletin

I'm trying to get vBulletin 5 up and running under lighttpd but I'm having some problems with url rewriting.  Here is the apache .htaccess provided by vBulletin.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]

#needed because admincp is an actual directory.
RewriteRule ^(admincp/)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If this helps, this is the IIS config provided by vBulletin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file is to support redirection in IIS.  It is harmless if you are running under Apache -->
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Admincp" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(admincp/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to the lighttpd url.rewrite equivalent?  All my experiments have failed thus far.

I'm running lighttpd-1.4.31-1

I tried this but it didn't work.  I think it has something to do with me not properly emulating [QS] in the .htaccess

```
url.rewrite-once = ("^(.*)$" => "index.php?routestring=$1",
                    "^(admincp/)$)" => "index.php?routestring=$1")
```

This has gotten me closer but not fully functional yet.

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("^(.*)$" => "index.php?routestring=$1",
                    "^(admincp/)$)" => "index.php?routestring=$1")
```

Comment: Which version of Lighttpd?

Comment: I added my lighttpd version number.  As for what I tried so far, I can't even begin to recall all my changes.  I'll add a few attempts I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression is applied to the entire request URI, including the query string, so you need to [deal with it explicitly](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite#Passing-Matching-the-Query-string-GET-variables). Try something like this:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^/([^\?]+)(\?(.*))?$" => "index.php?routestring=$1&$3",
)
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/(admincp/[^\?]+)(\?(.*))?$" => "index.php?routestring=$1&$3",
)
```

The second one for `/admincp/` may not be necessary since `rewrite-if-not-file` doesn't match directories.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that did the trick I think.  I'm going to do some more testing to confirm.